# R - "Error: object '<myvariable>' not found", but I have already defined

Tags: r

```
x <- c(1, 2, 3)
mean(x)
```

The console will display "Error: object x not found".

But if I only type `x <- c(1, 2, 3)`  then press run, the x will successfully exist.

I think directly complete the code then press run should be successfully executed, but why it can't execute normally?

Comment: I can't replicate this behavior. How exactly are you running this code? Are you using the default R GUI? Or RStudio? Is this something you are typing at the console, or in an editor? Is this a regular script or an R Markdown document?

Comment: In RSudio. I think I solved the problem. The run icon is “run by line”, and I should run all the line. But still thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

The `data` function is used to read in datasets, not to create objects - see `?data`. It looks like you want to create a vector, for which you need to use `c`:

```
x <- c(1, 2, 3)
mean(x)
```

Comment: Sorry, it's my mistake. I have revised it.